# OpenMP with C++: Internal Compiler Error with parallelized Lambda in Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, openmp

I have code that calls a template function which defines a lambda and then calls it. When trying to parallelize the lambda using a custom reduction in OpenMP, I get an internal compiler error. I'm using gcc (gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230201) inside a zsh shell.

Here is a **MWE** of the error:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T add(std::size_t const &maxs) {
  auto step = [&](auto const &maxs) {
    T a = T(0);
#pragma omp declare reduction(MyRed:T                                     \
                              : omp_out += omp_in)                             \
    initializer(omp_priv(omp_orig))
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 10) reduction(MyRed : a)
    for (std::size_t s = 0; s <= maxs; ++s) {
      a += T(1);
    }
    return a;
  };

  return step(maxs);
}

int main() {
  auto a = add<double>(100);

  std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
}
```

The compiler stumbles on line 6: `#pragma omp declare reduction(MyRed:double`.

It compiles fine if `add()` is not templated, the OpenMP directives are not in a Lambda, or the Lambda takes no arguments.

**Question**:
I'm aware this is a compiler bug which should be reported, and I'll do so (**edit**: [I did](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109490)). But is the error caused by me writing bad code?

If not, is there a way how I can retain the same code structure but get the compiler to understand me? I need to have the structure of main calling a template function calling a parallelized lambda.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: no matter what code you write, an internal compiler error is always an internal compiler error.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The question of the OP is about 1) the validity of their code, and 2) a possible workaround

Comment: @SirVivor Please add the following details: 1) which compiler and version; 2) the command line you are compiling with; 3) the error message

Comment: The code as-is compiles and runs with Intel compilers, both classic and llvm-based (at least version 2022.2.1+). With g++ version 10.3.0, it doesn't and generates and error `user defined reduction not found for ‘a’`. Moving the `#pragma omp declare reduction` up just before the `template` line fixes the issue. This is where I would have put it in the first place, but IDK if its current location is acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround that worked for my case, and thought I'd share it in case someone had a similar problem (unlikely, I know...):

Specifying the type of the argument in the lambda function made the compiler understand the code again:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T add(std::size_t const &maxs) {
  auto step = [&](std::size_t const &maxs) {
    T a = T(0);
#pragma omp declare reduction(MyRed:T                                     \
                              : omp_out += omp_in)                             \
    initializer(omp_priv(omp_orig))
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 10) reduction(MyRed : a)
    for (std::size_t s = 0; s <= maxs; ++s) {
      a += T(1);
    }
    return a;
  };

  return step(maxs);
}

int main() {
  auto a = add<double>(100);

  std::cout << "a=" << a << std::endl;
}
```